# Expected value of square of dot product of two vectors.

Tags: vectors, expectation

I have a random variable $\epsilon_n$, which is a column vector dependent on $n$, and another vector $w$, which is constant. How do I find the expectation $E[(w^T\epsilon_n)^2]$? It is given that the expected value of $\epsilon_n$ is zero.

My intuition was to write it as $(E[w^T\epsilon_n])^2+Var(w^T\epsilon_n)$, which then becomes $Var(w^T\epsilon_n)$, as the expectation of inner product of a constant vector and another vector is simply the inner product of that constant vector times the expectation of the other(follows from definition of expectation), which in this case is 0. Now I know from the scalar case that $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$, where $a$ is a scalar constant. But can I conclude similarly here that $Var(w^T\epsilon_n)=||w||^2Var(\epsilon_n)$?

Comment: Variance for random vectors is defined as  $Var(X)=E[XX^T]-E[X]E[X]^T. $

Comment: Yes, but $w^T\epsilon_n$ is not a vector, it is a scalar (inner product to be precise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the given problem,\begin{align}\mathrm{var}(w^{\top}\epsilon_n)&=w^{\top}\mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_n)w,
\end{align} 
where $\mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_n)=E[\epsilon_n \epsilon_n^{\top}]$, since $\epsilon_n$ is a zero mean random vector.

Comment: How did you get this expression?

Comment: For a transformation $S$ and vector $X$, $cov(SX)=Scov(X)S^{\top}$. Since $SX$ is a scalar in the problem, it can simply be written as $var(SX)$.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That really was useful.

Comment: Thus the expression given by @Shab is different from the expression you have proposed $Var(w^T\epsilon_n)=||w||^2Var(\epsilon_n)$ unless $Var(\epsilon_n)=Id_n$...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make that assumption, for if $w = e_2$, the standard basis vector along the $y$-axis, and $\epsilon_n = U e_1$, where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1, 1]$, then $w \cdot \epsilon_n = 0$, while $\|w\| Var(\epsilon_n) \ne 0$.

On the other hand, if $\epsilon_n = U e_2$, then it works out OK.

In short: that last step requires knowing something more about the relationship between $\epsilon_n$ and $w$.

Comment: So how do I calculate the Expected value then? i get it that my intuition is wrong.